# Error while extracting only text from a string in a column into another column in python dataframe using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract only text part into a new column from a string data in rows of a column in pandas dataframe.

When I tried something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [1,2] , "Text" : ["This is 20/06/2019; 00:13:45; Time stamp", "This is another 23/04/2019 11:23:35 Time stamp"]})

print(df)
```

I got a dataframe as below:

```
   Id                                            Text
0   1          This is 20/06/2019; 00:13:45; Time stamp
1   2  This is another 23/04/2019 11:23:35 Time stamp
```

This is fine.

And then I tried to extract the only text data from the string in each row of column:

```
df['Text2']= re.findall(r'\w+', df['Text'])
```

This is where I got the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b04317009801> in <module>
----> 1 df['Text2']= re.findall(r'\w+', df['Text'])
      2 
      3 print(df)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    221 
    222     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 223     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    224 
    225 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Whereas I was expecting something like this:

```
   Id                        Text
0   1          This is Time stamp
1   2  This is another Time stamp
```

What wrong have I done, here?

Comment: Pandas has its own method for vectorized string operations https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html

Comment: What is "text data"? How can you describe it? Do you just want to remove timestamps?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Timestamp is in these cases only, there can be any other numbers, special characters etc in between text. I want to retrieve only text part from the complete data in each row. I also was wondering what I should be doing when I only want to extract words that are greater than 2 characters.

Comment: Do you happen to have words in other languages than English? Then you can't rely on `[a-zA-Z]`, you need `[^\W\d_]`. As for 2+ char words, use `df['Text'].str.findall(r'[^\W\d_]{2,}').str.join(' ')`. 3+ char words can be extracted with `r'[^\W\d_]{3,}'` and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much Wiktor.. I didn't think on this. Yes there is a very much possibility of Foreign language words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) with regex for get text in length 3 or more characters:

```
df['Text2']= df['Text'].str.findall(r'[A-Za-z]{3,}').str.join(' ')
print(df)
   Id                                            Text                    Text2
0   1        This is 20/06/2019; 00:13:45; Time stamp          This Time stamp
1   2  This is another 23/04/2019 11:23:35 Time stamp  This another Time stamp
```

Comment: But this is a list in the Text2 column. I don't want list. :(

Comment: Superb... this worked on this data, let me try on my DF now. Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering if this code can be tweaked to get only those words which are greater than 2 in characters?

Comment: @loveR - then use `df['Text2']= df['Text'].str.findall(r'[A-Za-z]{3,}').str.join(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using

```
df['Text2'] = df['Text'].str.findall(r'[^\W\d_]{3,}').str.join(' ')
```

Or, to match only whole words (i.e. only those not "glued" to numbers or underscores):

```
df['Text2'] = df['Text'].str.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]{3,}\b').str.join(' ')
```

The `[^\W\d_]{3,}` pattern will match 3 or more any Unicode letter chunks from the content you have in `Text` column.

The `.str.findall` will find all overlapping matches in the input string and output a list of these matches.

The `.str.join(' ')` will convert the list of values to a single space-separated string.

Comment: Awesome. This is looks even better. Let me try on my dataset now.

Comment: @loveR Note that the word boundaries may be too restrictive. However, if you plan to exclude specific words from matching, they will come in very handy.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputations, so can not like otherwise I would have liked your answer. Thank you so much for helping me understand how we can adopt different approaches in this case.